# Angularjs IE9 refresh strange behavior

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I found this issue when learning Angularjs's scope example. Here's my code:

```
<span data-ng-controller="Control1">
    <input id="a" data-ng-model="model1.input1">
    <input id="b" data-ng-model="model1.input1">
    The input is: <span id="c">{{model1.input1}}</span>
    The input is: <span id="d">{{model1.input1}}</span>
</span>
```

I can see it works, just the synzhronizing behavior is strange. When I start to type in either < input >, both < input > content are synchronized, but the view part {{model1.input1}} doesn't synchronize, sometimes only one {{model1.input1}} is synchronize. But if I double click the page, or select all text in the input box, both {{model1.input1}} are synchronized.

My browser is IE9, it works perfectly on firefox and chrome. Anyone have idea what's happening? Thanks.

Comment: try this incase it works. The input is: <span id="c" data-ng-bind="model1.input1"></span>    i dont have ie9 to try it out on unfortunately

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, the behavior is the same as original.

Comment: It's a known issue. The solution is to use Angular 1.2.0-rc.2 and ng-bind instead of curly brackets. Check this out: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngBind This demo works for me on IE9.

Comment: Thanks for the information. However, the Angular 1.2.0-rc.2 is even worth. After using ng-bind, when typing in the '<input>', the view doesn't update at all.

Comment: The problem seems that I have 2 input which direct to the same model. Would this be allowed?